# How to set focus to an element after browser search bar closed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am searching using the default search option in the browser. it searches and detects the text on the webpage.
 but upon closing the search bar on top the focus goes back to the entire page.

I want the focus to be on the searched element that is currently being highlighted.

I don't know how to approach this problem and is open to suggestion.

I **expect the focus to be on the highlighted element/text after closing the search bar,** but the actual output is, once I close the default browser search bar the focus goes back to the entire page.

thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can only work with the DOM. You can not access the address bar as it is not part of the DOM.

However, addressing your second question if you want to focus some element, here is how you can do it:

You can create a ref for that custom element and then just call `.focus()`

```
focusCustomElement = () => this.customElementRef && this.customElementRef.focus()

render(){
    <CustomElement
        ref={element => (this.customElementRef = element)}
    />
}
```

So, on calling `focusCustomElement()` CustomElement will get focus.

Comment: How would this trigger on closing the search bar in browser? Thank you for helping

Comment: You can't as it is not part of the DOM.

Comment: I am just clarifying my question when I use **ctrl+f** the search bar appears on the browser. and I use that to search for a particular text. upon finding the text on that long page. I need the focus to be on that text/element when I close the search bar. I cant understand how this code would help. this code will only point to a custom component. thak you

Comment: if you go to google pages you can see that once the searchbar is closed the focus directly goes to the highlighted element. this feature is exactly what I want on my website. is this not possible? Thank you